# Build a custom array in Laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel

I am looping the database to get a list of countries with continents.

```
array: [
 0 => array: [
   "country" => "BE"
   "continent" => "EU"
 1 => array: [
   "country" => "BG"
   "continent" => "EU"
 ]
...
 ]
```

From that result, I want to create an array that shows all the continents with the countries inside.

```
array:[
  0 => array: [
    "continent" => "EU"
    "countries" => [
      "country" => "BE"
      "country" => "BG"
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: loop over continents, within that loop, loop over countries. If country->continent == 'EU'. add it do the continent array

Comment: I don't want it only for EU but for all the continents, so it is not really efficient to check for all of them

Comment: What have you tried?  SO is not a code-writing service.  Do your results really have different keys like `continent` vs `continent_code`, or is that a typo?  Laravel query builder and Eloquent both return Collections, not arrays - is it really just an array you have?

Comment: It's a typo which I corrected. I converted the Collection to array

Comment: Maybe `groupBy('continent')` [method](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-groupby) for Collection is what you looking for? It will not return exactly the same result you wish, but it will group countries depends on continent - continent will be the key, and the value array of countries array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need just to group countries by continent, simple way to achieve this by `mapToGroups()` [method](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-maptogroups) for collections

```php
$input = [
    ['country' => 'BE', 'continent' => 'EU'],
    ['country' => 'BG', 'continent' => 'EU'],
    ['country' => 'BU', 'continent' => 'AF'],
    ['country' => 'BY', 'continent' => 'EU'],
];

$grouped = collect($input)
    ->mapToGroups(fn ($country) => [$country['continent'] => $country['country']])
    ->toArray(); // if you need array at the end
```

This will be resulted in

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Suppose this is your array

```
 $arr = [
    [
        "country" => "BE",
        "continent" => "EU",
    ],
    [
        "country" => "BG",
        "continent" => "EU",
    ]
];
```

Then this returns what you expected.

```
collect($arr)->groupBy('continent')->mapWithKeys(function ($group, $continent) {
    return [
        'continent' => $continent,
        'countries' => $group->pluck('country')->toArray()
    ];
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to some how group your results by the **continent**. One way to do that is to loop over the initial collection and build a new array keyed by the continent.

However, seeing that you are using Laravel just group the *collection* by the continent.

```php
$countries = [
    ['country' => 'A', 'continent' => 'aa'],
    ['country' => 'B', 'continent' => 'bb'],
    ['country' => 'C', 'continent' => 'aa'],
    ['country' => 'D', 'continent' => 'aa'],
    ['country' => 'E', 'continent' => 'aa'],
    ['country' => 'F', 'continent' => 'bb'],
];

// Because my data is an array I just turn that into a collection.
// But an Eloquent query builder ->get would already return a collection.
$continents = collect($countries)->groupBy('continent');

foreach ($continents as $continent => $items) {
    echo "Countries for " . $continent . "\n";
    foreach ($items as $country) {
        echo $country['country'] . "\n";
    }
}

/**
Output: 
Countries for aa
A
C
D
E
Countries for bb
B
F
**/
```